# How to make a simple update with Firebase and Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Why is Firebase not being updated when the button is pressed in this plunk?
http://plnkr.co/6FmAOarpdEg3ylKAkArg

Notice the item is added, but not persisted because a refresh makes it go away again.

I'm able to successfully read and display Firebase data.

In looking at the TodoSample controller I don't see they are doing anything special other than updating the model.

The Firebase settings have read/write enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use FireBase implicitly, change this explicit binding:

```
$scope.items = angularFireCollection(url);
```

to use the implicit binding:

```
angularFire(url, $scope, 'items', []);
```

If you want to keep the explicit binding, don't add items like this:

```
$scope.items.add({name: "Firebase", desc: "is awesome!"});
```

Instead add items like this:

```
$scope.items.push({name: "Firebase", desc: "is awesome!"});
```

Comment: Perfect thank you.  Before we close this out, was it possible to make it work using angularFireCollection also by adding an explicit update command?

Comment: excuse me, but what's the difference between the two? I can see in your second answer what you ment, but you should delete that one and put the update in this answer instead.

Comment: @gion_13 fixed, now there is a difference.  separately, the answer may still need help, i'm still trying to tell all the permutations and learn Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$scope.items.push({name: "Firebase", desc: "is awesome!"});
```

to

```
$scope.items.add({name: "Firebase", desc: "is awesome!"});
```

in your controller if you want use `angularFireCollection`.